# Distribution of a random measure is determined by the characteristic function

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, random, stochastic-integrals

I ham trying to understand a proof from a book I am reading. It says the proof follows directly from the prior theorem and I just can't see that.

Let $X$ be a [random measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure) on a locally finite, seperable topological Room $E$.

**Theorem**: The distribution $P_X$ of a random measure X is defined by both the values of the Laplace-Transformation $L_X(f), f \in C^+_c(E)$ and the values of the characteristic function $\phi_X(f), f \in C_c(E)$
with
$$L_X(f) = \mathbb{E}[exp(-\int f dX)]$$
$$\phi_X(f) = \mathbb{E}[exp(i\int f dX)]$$
**Proof**: This follows directly from the prior theorem and the Laplace-transformation/the characteristic function being unique.

I am sitting here for some while now and not seeing it. The **prior theorem** is:

The distribution $P_X$ of a random measure X is distinctly determined by the distribution of
$$((I_{f_1}, .., I_{f_n}): n \in \mathbb{N}; f_1, ... ,f_n \in C_c^+(E))$$
as well as by the distribution of
$$((I_{A_1}, ..., I_{A_n}): n \in \mathbb{N}; A_1, ..., A_n \in B_b(E), A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset \text{ for } i \neq j)$$

With

- $I_f(\mu) = \int f d\mu$
- $I_A(\mu) = \mu(A)$
- $B_b$ the relative compact borel sets (their closure is compact)

**Any** help, tips, whatsoever are highly appreciated!

Comment: What's the relation between $X$ and $\mu$?

Comment: Btw *Raum* in this context translates to “space”, not “room”

Answer (score 1):

Argue something like this: Suppose $\phi_X(f) = \phi_{X'}(f)$ for every $f$. Pick sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ in $B_b$ and constants $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ and put $f=\sum t_i \chi_{A_i}$, where $\chi_{A_i}$ is the indicator function of set $A_i$ (taking value $1$ on $A_i$ and $0$ elsewhere). By assumption,
$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(i\int f\, dX)] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(i\int f\, dX')]\tag{*}
$$
But $\int f\,dX=\int\sum t_i\chi_{A_i}\,dX = \sum t_i\int \chi_{A_i}\,dX=\sum t_i X(A_i)$. The equality (*) holds for all choices of $t_1,\ldots,t_n$, so by uniqueness of characteristic functions in $\mathbb R^n$, the collection $(X(A_1),\ldots,X(A_n))$ has the same joint distribution as the collection $(X'(A_1),\ldots,X'(A_n))$. Now apply the second half of the prior theorem.

Comment: Why is that enough?

Comment: The prior theorem cites an alternative characterization of uniqueness: The distribution $P_X$ of a random measure $X$ is distinctly determined by the distribution of $((I_{A_1}, ..., I_{A_n}): n \in \mathbb{N}; A_1, ..., A_n \in B_b(E))$. By your notation, $I_A$ is the same as $X(A)$.

Comment: If $I_A$ = $X(A)$ I'd understand your proof. But as I see it, for you $\int I_A dX =: X(A)$, so that I cannot use the prior theorem

Comment: Ah, there's some ambiguity about what $I_A$ represents. In my definition of $f=\sum t_i I_{A_i}$, I'm taking $I_{A_i}$ to be the indicator of set $A_i$, i.e., the function taking value 1 on set $A_i$ and zero elsewhere.  It's rather unfortunate that we now have two interpretations of the notation $I_A$ such that one could write $\int I_A dX = X(A) = I_A$

Comment: If you edit that in your answer (I defined $I_A$ in the question already), then I will mark your answer as right because you where first

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

If $f \in C_c(E)$, then $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}: t * f \in C_c$. For $f_1, ... f_n \in C_c(E), t \in \mathbb{R^n}$ set $f = (f_1, ..., f_n)$

$$\phi_X(t \cdot f) = \mathbb{E}[\exp(i t \cdot I_f(X))] = \int_E \exp(it \cdot x) d\mathbb{P}_{I_f \circ X}$$

From the uniqueness of the characteristic function $\mathbb{P}_{I_f \circ X}$ is uniquly defined through this. From the prior theorem we know that because we chose $(f_1, ..., f_n)$ arbitary this uniquly defines the distribution $\mathbb{P}_{X}$